# BX cable connection to vapor tight luminaire

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I have some vaportight luminaires that I plan to install in a garage. The garage has bare stud walls, so all wiring is run in 3/8" BX armored cable. The luminaires came with a cable gland connection and approximately 1 ft of SOOW wire stubbed out. I can open the fixture and remove the wiring, but the BX cable is much too large to fit through the gland. My understanding of the electrical Code (Salt Lake City) is that all exposed wiring in garages has to be protected from damage. I don't believe SOOW wiring is rated for permanent installation. How should I connect the BX cable to this light?

Comment: Can you post photos of the installation instructions for the luminaires? Is there enough room to gland the free end of the SOOW whip into a "side" j-box for the splice to the armored cable?

Answer (score 1):

The normal thing is to either add a plug to that cord or tie it in at a junction box. MFG instructions override code in this case. Current code in a garage if an receptacle it must have GFCI protection no exceptions.

Comment: No exceptions even for freezer or fridge? I thought a non-GFI circuit was acceptable for those...

Comment: If a local exception allows it but the 2017 code doesn’t allow it. For example in Oregon table 1 E of the revised statues states if the device is not easily moved the GFCI device can be omitted.